# I am new in word pres my font awesome is not allow

Tags: htaccess

i have error in console 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin  is therefore not allowed access.
my ht-access file look like this..

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: it's because you are including any file in wrong way from any other domain, and for WordPress you should use wp_enqueue_script() to add any CSS or JS.

Answer (score 1):

Enqueue the script or style using wp_enqueue_script() or wp_enqueue_style()